# Enovy error - The following ciphers were rejected when tried individually: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

Tags: ssl, istio, gateway, tls1.3

In `istio` 1.5.1, when I tried to add a particular cipher suit to the `gateway`'s `tls` section using this syntax:

```
      minProtocolVersion: TLSV1_3
      mode: SIMPLE
      cipherSuites: [TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
```

I got the following error in the istio-ingress pod's logs:

```
[Envoy (Epoch 0)] [2020-06-08 15:15:44.033][22][warning][config] [external/envoy/source/common/config/grpc_subscription_impl.cc:87]
gRPC config for type.googleapis.com/envoy.api.v2.Listener rejected: 
Error adding/updating listener(s) 0.0.0.0_443: Failed to initialize cipher suites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256.
The following ciphers were rejected when tried individually: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

If I remove the `cipherSuites` line from the `tls` section, there is no errors, and the same cipher suit appears in the list of valid cipher suits.

Any advise? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I checked in envoy [documentation](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/v3/common.proto.html?highlight=cipher) And BoringSSL [documentation](https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/+/f0bdf5c9a10ba7172001aece1ed4908830eebea2/include/openssl/ssl.h#1432)

> **TLS 1.3 ciphers do not participate in this mechanism and instead have a
> built-in preference order**. **Functions to set cipher lists do not affect TLS
> 1.3**, and functions to query the cipher list do not include TLS 1.3
> ciphers.

---

### cipher_suites

> If specified, the TLS listener will only support the specified cipher list when negotiating TLS 1.0-1.2 (this setting has no effect when negotiating TLS 1.3). If not specified, the default list will be used.
>
> In non-FIPS builds, the default cipher list is:

```
[ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256|ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305]
[ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256|ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305]
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
AES128-GCM-SHA256
AES128-SHA
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
AES256-GCM-SHA384
AES256-SHA
```

> In builds using BoringSSL FIPS, the default cipher list is:

```
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
AES128-GCM-SHA256
AES128-SHA
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
AES256-GCM-SHA384
AES256-SHA
```

---

Additionally take a look at this github [issue](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/8848#issuecomment-548672667).